# How do we contact Google Cloud around technical questions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm unclear on Google Cloud Platform support. If I want to email Google Cloud around technical questions on GCP products we are using, do we need to have more than just 'Basic' support?

For the 'Basic Role' listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/) it reads "Billing support and read-only access to break/fix cases". I also see "There is also a free Basic role that offers read-only access to support cases."

What I am confused about, is how is it possible to have read-only access to a support case, can you not create support cases under 'Basic'? And when they use the word 'case', is it the same as a 'support ticket request/email'?

Comment: This is a question for Google, not stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions regarding asking for ways to contact a product's support team should be asked on the relevant forum(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many ways to get support for Google Cloud Platform.

- [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/): You can find help from other users, technical support representatives, and engineers in Stackoverflow. You just need to add the adequate tags both for 'google-cloud-support' and for the product that you are requesting help. This isn't a guaranteed method to solve all your issues.
- [Cloud Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/): If you are using Google Cloud Platform you already are a customer, and all the customer of Google Cloud Platform are supported. Contacting with the billing team you can request them to open a new support case on your behalf even if you don't have a paid role support.
- [Role Based Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/): With the role based support you are paying for a faster support. The higher the tier of the support paid the faster you can get a response and a solution. With the highest tiers, you can also request screen-sharing/hangout sessions with a Google technical representative and you can get support in other languages i.e. Japanese.
- [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) This is a way to report any abnormal behavior which you suspect that may be a bug affecting you, or if you have an issue with an instance (i.e. Cloud SQL instance hanged and unresponsive) requiring action from Google.

For your specific use "asking technical questions" I would recommend you to pay the Role-Based Support Development package which will cover this requirement

Answer (score 0):

You have several types of support

[Role based support, you pay per user](https://cloud.google.com/support/)

- Basic: only for read only case, like a team leader to follow the case open by his team
- Development: for developer, for no urgent case, answer in less than 4H (100$ per month and per user)
- Production: for production and critical application, answer in less than 1H (250$ per month and per user)

For business critical, there is an [entreprise grade support](https://cloud.google.com/support/premium/). It's not per user but based on your Global billing on the platform. I don't think that it's your case

Finally, you have the [public tracked](https://issuetracker.google.com/). You have shortcut to the predefined topic [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list). This tracker is public (don't publish sensitive information) and the answer time is not guaranteed. But it's free!